# Renaming pictures where the name incl. _1 for every new day

Tags: python, list

I want to rename pictures in a windows directory. The filenames should look like this

2012-12-01_1
2012-12-01_2
2012-12-02_1
and so on

a new sequence must start with _1 for each new date. I tried comparing list elements in every possible way I could think of with no luck.

I got the time from :

```
datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(target,f)))
where f= each file
```

the list i created looks like this:
['IMG_0288.JPG', 'IMG_0289.JPG', 'IMG_0290.JPG', 'IMG_0291.JPG', 'IMG_0292.JPG', 'IMG_0293.JPG', 'IMG_0294.JPG', 'IMG_0295.JPG', 'IMG_0296.JPG', 'IMG_0297.JPG', 'IMG_0298.JPG', 'IMG_0299.JPG', 'IMG_0300.JPG', 'IMG_0301.JPG', 'IMG_0302.JPG', 'IMG_0303.JPG', 'IMG_0304.JPG', 'IMG_0305.JPG', 'IMG_0306.JPG', 'IMG_0315.JPG', 'IMG_0323.JPG', 'IMG_0324.JPG', 'IMG_0325.JPG', 'IMG_0326.JPG', 'IMG_0327.JPG', 'IMG_0328.JPG', 'IMG_0330.JPG', 'IMG_0331.JPG', 'IMG_0333.JPG', 'IMG_0334.JPG', 'IMG_0335.JPG', 'IMG_0336.JPG', 'IMG_0339.JPG', 'IMG_0340.JPG', 'IMG_0341.JPG', 'IMG_0342.JPG', 'IMG_0343.JPG', 'IMG_0344.JPG']

I tried comparing f with dir[0] and than cut dir[0] afterwards however it started skipping every other element. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools as it
import datetime
import os

get_day = lambda x: datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(target,f)))

for k, v in it.groupby(sorted(files, key=get_day), key=get_day):
    for i, f in enumerate(v, 1):
        os.rename(os.path.join(target, f),
                  os.path.join(target, '{0:%Y-%m-%d}_{}.JPG'.format(k, i)))
```

Comment: but     for k, v in it.groupby(sorted(files, key=get_day), key=get_day):
NameError: name 'files' is not defined

Comment: @user1945009 - replace it with the variable name of your list of files (or with `os.listdir('.')`)